# How to alternate Django Queryset by type

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am new to Django and I have an application that has ~60,000 "project" models in the database.

This amount is always going to be growing, "project" is a Django model that we made.  Our application routinely needs to display these projects on our site in a certain order.  We have 3 types of projects, I will call them type1, type2, type3.  Theses projects also expire at a certain time and the amount is always growing so we cannot create a static list and use that, it has to be dynamic.  We need to display the projects like(32 per page):

```
type1 type2 type3 type1
type2 type3 type1 type2 
type3 type1 type2 type3
type1 type2 type3 type1
type2 type3 type1 type2
type3 type1 type2 type3
type1 type2 type3 type1
type2 type3 type1 type2
```

We also have implemented infinite scroll to display these projects so the list needs to keep going in the same order. In example: page 2 from above would start with type3.

1. Right now we make 3 queries by each type.
2. Create a list of each.
3. Create another list.
4. Then iterate through and append the projects in alternating order onto the list in 3.
5. Create a Paginator and return the specific page.

I understand that this is VERY expensive, creating all of these list and iterating through them but I am struggling with a way to speed it up.  One way I have tried is [Memcached](http://memcached.org),

I store 1500 of the projects in Memcached and the response is very fast.  But when the key expires the application has to go through all of that again.  One thing I have thought of is to create a management command(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it from crontrab to ensure this list is always in memory.  We already run some commands in crontab(our data pulls) so this wouldn't be awful.

I also have tried taking advantage of the fact that you can use filter to create a QuerySet and it does not go to the database until it actually needs to.  But since we display 32 projects per page I am running into trouble with actually implementing this.  This is because it will display 10 of one type, 11 of another and 11 of another.

The amount of the different types is not the same. There is about:

> type1: ~500
>   type2: ~36,000
>   type3: ~24,000

Because of this I ran into trouble about what to do when type1 ended and also when type2 ended(very unlikely someone would get this far but still need to account for it).

EDIT: Thank you for the responses! This is for my school capstone project.  This is the first time that any of us have used python.  I have used Groovy and Grails before at an internship so I am familiar with the concept of ORM.   I will provide a little code:

```
def index(request):
    type1Projects = list(project.objects.filter(type=type1))
    type2Projects = list(project.objects.filter(type=type2))
    type3Projects = list(project.objects.filter(type=type3))

    projects = list()

    while(len(type1Projects) > 0 or len(type2Projects) > 0 or len(type3Projects) > 0) :
        if(len(type1Projects) > 0) :
            projects.append(type1Projects.pop(0))
        if(len(type2Projects) > 0) :
            projects.append(type2Projects.pop(0))
        if(len(type3Projects) > 0) :
            projects.append(type3Projects.pop(0))

    paginator = Paginator(projects, 32)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    render_to_response('fake.html', {'projects':paginator.page(page)}, RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see evaluating these queries and loading the list into memory has a  A LOT of overhead.  Then iterating through and creating the projects list takes a while as well.

Before our capstone client wanted the types alternating we were just returning like:

```
def index(request) :
    projects = projects.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(projects, 32)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    render_to_response('fake.html', {'projects':paginator.page(page)}, RequestContext(request))
```

These are simplified versions of this function just to demonstrate the concept.  The second one was fast because it only evaluates what it needs.  The alternating way takes entirely way too long because everything is loaded into memory and then iterated through.

This is the version that I tried to do to take advantage of Django QuerySet lazy evaluation:

```
def index(request) :
    type1Projects = project.objects.filter(type=type1)
    type2Projects = project.objects.filter(type=type2)
    type3Projects = project.objects.filter(type=type3)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    type1Pag = Paginator(type1Projects, 11)
    type2Pag = Paginator(type2Projects, 11)
    type3Pag = Paginator(type3Projects, 11)

    type1List = list(type1Pag.page(page))
    type2List = list(type2Pag.page(page))
    type3List = list(type3Pag.page(page))

    projects = list()

    while(len(type1List) > 0 or len(type2List) > 0 or len(type3List) > 0) :
        if(len(type1List) > 0) :
            projects.append(type1List.pop(0))
        if(len(type1List) > 0) :
            projects.append(type2List.pop(0))
        if(len(type3List) > 0) :
            projects.append(type3List.pop(0))


    render_to_response('fake.html', {'projects':projects}, RequestContext(request))
```

This version does work a lot faster and this is  a simpler version then was actually implemented because there was logic to tell which project type to start with and to limit it to 32 projects per page.  But then it misses 1 type of project per page.  Once you get to the farther pages I was struggling to implement the logic to start on say project #5 in the list of this type then go to the next page.

I hope this clarifies a little bit, sorry it was confusing last night...I am getting ready for finals and was tired/probably not thinking straight last night.  I will look into raw SQL and NoSql.

@Saransh Mohapatra What exactly do you mean using Redis or Memcache directly?  We use Memcache now to store the first 1500 projects from the list.  The problem is that we only want our key to be valid for 5-10 minutes.  So when the key expires and then someone goes to the site the response is slow for them.  That is why I was talking about creating a management command and then running it say every 4 minutes using crontab and letting the key be valid for 10 minutes.  If we did this then the list would always be in there but I am not sure this is the best way to go about this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would help to answer your question, if you have stated your inputs and your problem in more straightforward way. As stated, it is very difficult to understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: I'd suggest using raw sql (see django queryset raw). If SQL isn't your forte then ask on here for help building a query (tag your question 'SQL' and the name of your db). With some well written SQL `Project.objects.raw()` is likely to do this much more efficiently than django.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to suggest anything without looking at your code. But as far as I can guess your models dont have relationship and therefore it would be much faster if use NoSql rather than using traditional sql.

It would make it much faster and you dont have to cache every time. You might look at Reddis or even using memcache directly rather than just using it for only cache.
These are basically kind of key value store, So in your cache project can be the key and its details the value.
Have a look